# Save and Load Checkbox checked states to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a "settings" page in my site and I would like the user to be able to either check or uncheck checkboxes in the settings page. The checkboxes' states should then load when the user logs in.

My idea is to assign ids to each checkbox like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-col='column1' value="0"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" data-col='column2' value="0"/>
```

and then use jQuery to set the values for each on the checked function like this on the "SAVE SETTINGS" button:

```
$( "input:checkbox" ).each(function() {
   if $(this).prop('checked'){
    $(this).prop('value','1')
     }
});
```

and then have a column in my MySql table for each checkbox and then send the value (either 1 or 0) to my database via ajax/php.

Then when the user logs in, I can get the values (1 or 0) for each column and then based on that, I can set the checked state.

Is this a good way to go about it? I want to make sure I don't go down the wrong path if there is a simpler solution or approach.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that $query_array is the container of your db query. Since you've included php in the post's tag you can insert a php tag inside input(assuming the file is a php too):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-col='column1' value="<?php echo $query[0][col_name];?>"/>
```

^the 0 above might be an id, and col_name is the column name which contains 0/1

When that is compiled, it should be similar to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-col='column1' value="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I think I will use jquery to set the value from the ajax response from the php file.

Comment: it's not enough to set value to 1, but also to add attribute "checked" on each of them.

Comment: @Bruno, you're welcome! And jquery with the combination of ajax is a cool approach too since you want to just use html. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using jquery why don't you just render the checkboxes with their value already set:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-col='column1' value="<?php echo $chk1?>" <?php echo $checked?>/>
```

**Edit**

If you wanna keep it HTML only you could store the states in a JSON (where the property name is the id of the chekbox and the value it's state) and loop through it as:

```
$.each(jsonChkbxValues, function(index, val) {
    var elem = $('#' + index);

    elem.prop('value', val);
    if (val) {
        elem.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: I was going to use jQuery because I wanted to keep my page only html so I can port it to a mobile app easier. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: it's not enough to set value to 1, but also to add attribute "checked" on each of them.

Comment: Yes, attribute checked has to be added too, I corrected the answer @mitkosoft.

Comment: @Pablo.mtz, and how do you check which checkbox is checked or not before that? it's good practice to provide completed solution rather than a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks Pablo and mitkosoft, I will definitely be using this approach.